# Access static variable in extension in swift-ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Hi I have this extension for `NSUserDefaults` and I need to access it using Obj-C.

**Struct in Extension**

```
public struct UserDefaultsEntry {
    let key: String

    func get() -> AnyObject? {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key)
    }

    func set(value: AnyObject) {
        switch value {
        case is Bool:
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(value as! Bool, forKey: key)
            break
        case is String:
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value as! String, forKey: key)
            break
        case is NSData:
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value as! NSData, forKey: key)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func remove() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key)
    }
}
```

**Static Variable in same extension class**

```
public static let testDefault = UserDefaultsEntry(key: "testDefault")
```

so I can call it normally in swift class by using

```
let string = "test"
NSUserDefaults.testDefault.set(string)
```

but failed to call it in Obj-C class. So how can I call it? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Tried to use

```
[NSUserDefaults.testDefault get];
```

but I'm getting

> Property 'testDefault' not found on object type 'NSUserDefaults'

Answer (score 2):

Structs are not available in Objective-C. For code in Swift to be available in Objective-C, it must be a class that subclasses `NSObject`. `testDefault` is a struct, and therefore, can't be seen by Objective-C.